# Sharing data between cells of a row in a MatTable on Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I am developing an application in Angular using a lot Material Design tables.

Now, in some of these tables, the data can be edited, so I have several rows where each row has a series of column with some fields and the last column with some buttons that allow me to commit the changes to the data or revert back to the initial state.

The functionality is working pretty good, I can with no problem edit the data and everything, and now I was looking to improve the user experience by adding validation to the data and showing hint and errors under the inputs using `mat-hint` and `mat-error`

The problem is that I am not able to disable the "submit" button in case one of the fields of a row is not valid.

In other parts of the application, where there was no table, what I did was:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input name="data" #inputData="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="inputData.errors">
            some error
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but now I have

```
<mat-table>
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="input">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Input </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
      <input [(ngModel)]="row.data" name="data" #inputData="ngModel"/>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row;">
      <button (click)="submitData(row)">
        Submit
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['id', 'input', 'actions']"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: ['id', 'input', 'actions'];"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

How can I achieve the same effect? I know that simply using `inputData` doesn't work because it is a template variables and rows, headers and cell definitions are all in different templates. I would really like to avoid adding stuff to the row, since that is my model variable and I would like to keep things separated.

I can show errors, the main thing I want to achieve is disabling the submit button in case some fields are invalid in a table organized like the one here above.